# GPG file encryption

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I have tried to encrypt file with GPG. Use "gpg -e -r 'Recipient' message.txt".

Why I got this:
[image: My pgp message]

Instead of something like this:

[image: Normal pgp message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get output like I want. You should append option -a, "ascii output".